# how to create 3 variables equal together.

Tags: batch-file, if-statement

i am making a code which identify if its equilateral, isosceles and scalene but i am having trouble coding at equilateral part because the size should be equal here's my code.

```
:triangle
echo enter the three size:
echo size a
set /p s1=
echo size b
set /p s2=
echo size c
set /p s3=

:: Isosceles triangle 

if %s1%==%s2% (
    goto isosceles
    ) else if %s1%==%s3% (
    goto isosceles
    ) else ( 
    goto scalene
    )
pause

:: equilateral triangle

if %s1%==%s2%==%s3% (
    goto equilateral
)   
pause   

:: for triangles 
:equilateral
echo the triangle is equilateral 
goto pause
:scalene
echo the triangle is scalene 
goto pause 
:isosceles
echo the triangle is isosceles 
goto pause
```

is my equilateral statement correct?

Comment: `if %s1%==%s2% && %s2%==%s3% && %s3%==%s1%` ?

Comment: if %s1%==%s2% && %s2%==%s3% && %s3%==%s1% (
 goto equilateral
) like that??

Comment: my cmd close immeditely after :C

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may also use this simpler approach:

```
@echo off

echo Enter the three sizes:
set /p "s1=size a: "
set /p "s2=size b: "
set /p "s3=size c: "

rem Next line means: s1=s2 AND s2=s3 (all sides are equal)
if "%s1%/%s2%" equ "%s2%/%s3%" goto equilateral

rem Next line means that all sides are different
if "%s1%" neq "%s2%" if "%s2%" neq "%s3%" if "%s3%" neq "%s1%" goto scalene

::isosceles
echo the triangle is isosceles 
pause & goto :eof

:scalene
echo the triangle is scalene 
pause & goto :eof

:equilateral
echo the triangle is equilateral 
pause & goto :eof
```

Answer (score 0):

`if` doesn't support `a==b==c`.
Also there isn't any `AND` or `OR`.
Instead you can use `if %a%==%b% if %b%==%c% echo equilateral`

You should check for equilateral first to prevent "early isosceles detection":

```
@echo off
echo enter the three sizes:
set /p "s1=size a: "
set /p "s2=size b: "
set /p "s3=size c: "
:: equilateral triangle
if "%s1%"=="%s2%" if "%s2%"=="%s3%" goto equilateral
REM if s1=s2 and s2=s3 then also s1=s3
:: Isosceles triangle 
if "%s1%"=="%s2%" goto isosceles
if "%s1%"=="%s3%" goto isosceles
if "%s2%"=="%s3%" goto isosceles

:: scalene 
echo the triangle is scalene 
pause & goto :eof
:equilateral
echo the triangle is equilateral 
pause & goto :eof
:scalene
echo the triangle is scalene 
pause & goto :eof 
:isosceles
echo the triangle is isosceles 
pause & goto :eof
```